# It's possible to use same order number to reorder?

Tags: orders, customer, reorder

I need to edit the customer order **(reorder)** and I need to **reorder** have the same order id. In the original Magento Core, every time I edit the order, it gets a new ID. I need to apply the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the order number is a unique database column and there is code that relies on fetching a distinct order by order number, so you should not change it